# Associations many to many but not so much

Tags: go, go-gorm

I try to setup a pretty simple association but can't manage it :

```
Type Books struct {
   gorm.model
   Name        string
   Tags        []Tag `gorm:"many2many:books_tags_relations;association_autoupdate:true;association_autocreate:true;"`
}

Type Tag struct {
    gorm.Model
    Label   string
    Niveau  string
}
```

the books share an amount of around 30 to 40 tags for now
each book can have multiple tags
each tag can be hooked to any number of books

for example the tag:  "humour noir" can be only once in the table tags but used in 20 differents books.

```
if err := db.Debug().Model(&book).Association("Tags").Append(&tag); err != nil {
        log.Errorf("[ERROR] erreur en sauvant les derniers tag %+v\n", err)
}
```

{EDIT} :

```
if err := db.Debug().Model(&book).Association("Tags").Append(&tag).Error; err != nil {
            log.Errorf("[ERROR] erreur en sauvant les derniers tag%v\n", err)
        }
```

no more error ... but I still have to understand why I got multiple time the same tag in the table ...
{/EDIT}

and I got :

> [ERROR] erreur en sauvant les derniers tag &{Error:
>   scope:0xc42039ad00 column:Tag field:0xc42051cea0}

The other main problem is that multiple same tag are saved!

I want only one line pour the same tags, no need to have 1 per book/tag...

What am I doing wrong?

(Pretty sure, everything is in there but no way to get it out : https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/association_test.go)

Comment: Format the error with %s or %v and include the actual error message. %+v is useless here.

Comment: this doesn't change much : [ERROR] erreur en sauvant les derniers tags &{<nil> 0xc420fdb880 Tag 0xc4221ac600}

Comment: Print err.Error() then. We can't help without knowing the error message.

Comment: this explain the ERROR which is not one .... see my edit !